# Classpath error on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, classpath

I made a Java application which runs another Java code using the `java -cp "xxx.jar;xxx.jar" net.minecraft.client.main.Main`command. The `;` (or `:`depending on the OS) between the two JAR of the classpath is provided by the `System.getProperty("path.separator")` function.

On Windows it works fine, but not on Mac OS. Java says it cannot find or load main class `net.minecraft.client.main.Main`. I checked, the JARS of the classpath are correctly spelled and existing on the hard drive at the proper path.

Here is the whole command (`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java` is the path to the Java executable) :

http://pastebin.com/8V3pg07q

Could you help me ? I am NOT requiring help on how to play Minecraft, it is not the official launcher (it is one I've made, which obviously doesn't work on Mac OS), so don't tell me to ask help at Minecraft Forums :P

Thanks !

Comment: you mean File.pathSeparator?

Comment: @rupps: Well, I suspect the OP means `System.getProperty("path.separator")`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you meant by "I tested forcing usage of `;` even on Mac OS" but basically you should use the right path separator for the platform when you run the new Java process.

So on Windows you'd want:

```
java -cp xxx.jar;yyy.jar
```

On Unix you'd want

```
java -cp xxx.jar:yyy.jar
```

In the code where you're building the command line arguments, just make sure you use the `path.separator` property (or more simply [`File.pathSeparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator)) appropriately so that you can build the right command line without having to detect the actual operating system.

EDIT: I don't know why this isn't currently working for you, unless it's because the command line itself is too long.

You could consider putting all the relevant jar files into a single directory, and then using:

```
java -cp 'somedirectory/*' net.minecraft.client.main.Main
```

Alterantively, use the [extensions mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/index.html)... but that's a last resort, and may cause other issues.

Comment: I tried using `;` on Mac because I was not sure that `:`was the right one, seemed weird to me, but now I keep the `path.separator` ^^

Comment: @natinusala: Well it's hard to tell from your question, because it's unclearly worded. There's no indication in your question that you ever tried the colon as a separator in the Mac version. I suggest you edit your question with more details - including how you're starting the process, and where *exactly* the jar files are.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope to be more clear now (I'm not english so there might be some errors)

Comment: @natinusala: Well which of those jar files contains `net.minecraft.client.main.Main`?

Comment: It's 1.7.5.jar, the first one of the list.

Comment: @natinusala: That's a very odd name for a jar file, which makes me somewhat suspicious. What happens if you run `jar tvf "/Users/etiennep/Library/Application Support/launchmycraft/common/versions/1.7.5/1.7.5.jar"`?

Comment: The JAR file is valid, the class is in it because it works fine on Windows, the issue doesn't seem to be here.

Comment: @natinusala: If you run *just* `java -cp "/Users/etiennep/Library/Application Support/launchmycraft/common/versions/1.7.5/1.7.5.jar" net.minecraft.client.main.Main` (from the command line) what happens? And what is the *full* error message when you try it with the complete command line? Please edit this information into the question.

Comment: The error is `Cannot find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main`. The command result will come later, I wait for my friend to do it and answer me ^^

Comment: When I do only the `java -cp "[...]1.7.5.jar" net.minecraft.client.main.Main` command, the class is loading because there is a Minecraft error saying that the dependencies (other JARs of the classpath) are not present, so the problem is in the Mac classpath.

Comment: @natinusala: Right, but it's a different error. Interesting. I'm afraid I'm stuck at this point - I think it *should* work...

Comment: I agree it should work, maybe there is a spelling mistake on the whole command so Java can't read the classpath properly ?

Comment: @natinusala: No, I wouldn't expect so. Even if some elements of the classpath don't exist, you should still get the dependencies error. I have an alternative suggestion though - amending my answer now...

Comment: The command line is actually an array executed by a ProcessBuilder, I don't think the issue is because of its size ; the official Minecraft launcher is doing it the same way and it works fine.

Comment: @natinusala: Well as I can't compare what the Minecraft launcher is doing and what you're doing, and I can't try further things to diagnose the problem, I'm afraid I'm stuck - I've given all the ideas I've got.